# Monogame 3.2 in Visual Studio 2013 doesn't work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, monogame

I've already edited the vstemplate file to change the version number from 11.0 to 12.0 like the answer to a similar question says on here, but that only makes Visual Studio crash after a create a Windows Store XAML Monogame project instead of giving me the version error. The project ends up getting created, but after I restart visual studio it doesn't want to open any of the source files even after I retarget the project to Windows 8.1. Im using visual studio 2013 express btw.

Comment: I've had some troubles too, with the most recent "stable" version. Try pulling the source from https://github.com/mono/MonoGame and build it yourself. Solved all of my problems, as far as I recall. Perhaps I should mention, I'm on VS2012, however 2012 and 2013 seems pretty similar, so I'm guessing it should still work

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of problems, I found a better way of getting it to work.

- First install Visual studio 2013 (or 2012, that will work too)
- [Download XNA 4.0 Refresh](https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases/view/117230) and install it
- [Download MonoGame 3.2](http://www.monogame.net/releases/MonoGameInstaller-3.2.exe) and install it

Then you can start using the MonoGame templates in Visual Studio without problems.

Haven't tried it for a Store app, but it fixed all my other problems with Visual Studio 2013 and MonoGame. I used Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop to test it.

Comment: thanks for the input but I didn't have any problems with regular desktop app templates, its only the new Windows Store App templates that don't seem to work

Comment: I tried the Windows Store XAML template and it gave me an error at first, I changed the version number from 11.0 to 12.0 (just like you mentioned) and then, the project loaded fine. I then retargetted the project to Windows 8.1.. the project still works. When I run the game, I get the default Cornflower blue screen from XNA. I will upload my WindowsStoreXaml template and the test project. Maybe you can compare/start from the new project or something. link: [Template and Project files](http://users.telenet.be/tourist/Project_and_Template_Files.zip)

Comment: thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it, but for some reason it still doesn't work. Visual Studio crashes whenever I try to open any of the source files or build the project, even when I used the files that you provided